# Why my changes on template files are not showing up?

Tags: magento

I am working on Magento and trying to make some changes on one of the .phtml files. But my changes never reflect on the web site. I have tried the following things:

1. Clear Magento cache and delete cache storage
2. Open the path hint and make sure I am editing the correct file
3. Go to magento admin panel, System->Configuration->Design, and make sure templates, skin, layout and default folders are correct.

None of the above action worked. Is there anything else that I could do?

Thanks a lot.

Screen shot
[image]

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 4):

First thing you would want to check is the cache. System > Cache Management. Disable the Layout and Blocks HTML output caches and refresh the frontend page where you've put your changes.

If cache isn't the problem there is a way to find out which template is rendered in a specific location because you may not be editing the correct file.
Go to System > Configuration, select your website from top left Current Configuration Scope, then go to Developer > Debug and set Template Path Hints to Yes.
After this, save your config and refresh the page where you want to modify the .phtml.

If you are working on a live environment make sure not everybody will be able to see the template paths by putting your IP in the Allowed IPs input from Developer Client Restrictions.

After you are finished with this re-enable the cache.